# How to get the value of converted money in PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

My currency_code is in USD but it is converted to PHP after donated
My problem is when I insert it on my database, the USD is being inserted but not the converted PHP value. for example: I donated 10USD is it equivalent to more or less 450PHP, how can I insert 450 in my database?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem on your code is not the Paypal API it is the setting of the variables.

```
$donation = $_POST["donation"]; // this is sample return value
$converted_donation = convent_donation($donation); // function that convert USD to PHP

you are inserting the $donation variable I guess, that's why your data is wrong
```

anyway, you can set the currency code in the paypal api to PHP and insert it directly on your database, there is no need to convert it

```
 $config["currency_code"] = 'PHP';
```

Comment: I can't use different currency because of the different values, some might converted to zero like 10 PHP to USD. it is equivalent to 0.0000something. minus the gross. It would be safe to use only one currency. But if you have better idea that might be useful for me then, I think it's way better than my idea.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're converting the value after the PayPal response is returned? In which case, are you sure you're not just inserting the wrong variable (such as the value returned in the response directly)?